# Non-blocking analogRead for Arduino Nano 33 BLE sense

Tags: analogread, arduino-nano-ble

I need an alternative to `analogRead()` that doesn't block the processor. I've managed to find a lot of solutions for this for other boards, but not something that's compatible with nrf5240 like the one that's on Arduino Nano 33 BLE sense. Does something like this already exist? Would it be difficult to make?

Comment: It has mbed-os rtos, so you can do it in another thread. Or you can read nRF58240 Product specification and use EasyDMA (it has even sample rate, multiple channels setup, ..)